# How to make the large scrolling word in this header centered within its containing element and not disappear as window size is reduced?

Tags: wordpress, css-position, absolute, divi, extra

I'm only a few months into learning CSS/HTML, and this is my first Stack Exchange question, so please bear with me. Also hoping it's okay to ask this question even if I'm using a theme instead of 100% straight coding.

I can't figure out which elements should have relative and which should have absolute positioning. When I set the column to relative and the text module to absolute (center), the text module disappears and I can't ever find it again, even when I try to adjust the vertical positioning, etc.

My original goal was to have the giant word scrolling as the visitor moves down the page. And so far that works fairly well on desktop. But things get messy when the window is minimized or when viewed on a phone especially. The scrolling word disappears and the various sections end up overlapping.

Note: I used Extra Theme Builder to create the header sections and Extra Category Builder to create the body section of the page.

The page I'm troubleshooting is here: https://www.wayflowhub.com/posts/fantastic-new-3d-assets-for-the-digitally-inclined.

Comment: The display of this section is set to none on mobile devices https://prnt.sc/_LF8p4F6uGpD